# python can't start a new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am building a multi threading application.

I have setup a threadPool.
 [ A Queue  of size N and N Workers that get data from the queue]

When all tasks are done I use

```
tasks.join()
```

where tasks is the queue .

The application seems to run smoothly until suddently at some point (after 20 minutes in example) it terminates with the error

```
thread.error: can't start new thread
```

Any ideas?

Edit: The threads are daemon Threads and the code is like:

```
while True:
    t0 = time.time()
    keyword_statuses = DBSession.query(KeywordStatus).filter(KeywordStatus.status==0).options(joinedload(KeywordStatus.keyword)).with_lockmode("update").limit(100)
    if keyword_statuses.count() == 0:
        DBSession.commit()
        break

    for kw_status in keyword_statuses:
       kw_status.status = 1
       DBSession.commit()

    t0 = time.time()
    w = SWorker(threads_no=32, network_server='http://192.168.1.242:8180/', keywords=keyword_statuses, cities=cities, saver=MySqlRawSave(DBSession), loglevel='debug')

    w.work()

print 'finished'
```

When the daemon threads are killed?
When the application finishes or when the work() finishes?

Look at the thread pool and the worker (it's from a recipe )

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread, Event, current_thread
import time

event = Event()

class Worker(Thread):
    """Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""

    def __init__(self, tasks):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()


    def run(self):
        '''Start processing tasks from the queue'''
        while True:
            event.wait()
            #time.sleep(0.1)
            try:
                func, args, callback = self.tasks.get()
            except Exception, e:
                print str(e)
                return
            else:
                if callback is None:
                    func(args)
                else:
                    callback(func(args))

                self.tasks.task_done()

class ThreadPool:
    """Pool of threads consuming tasks from a queue"""

    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)
        for _ in range(num_threads): Worker(self.tasks)


    def add_task(self, func, args=None, callback=None):
        ''''Add a task to the queue'''
        self.tasks.put((func, args, callback))


    def wait_completion(self):
        '''Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue'''
        self.tasks.join()


    def broadcast_block_event(self):
        '''blocks running threads'''
        event.clear()


    def broadcast_unblock_event(self):
        '''unblocks running threads'''
        event.set()


    def get_event(self):
        '''returns the event object'''
        return event
```

ALSo maybe the problem it's because I create SWorker objects in a loop?
What happens with the old SWorker (garbage collection ?) ?

Comment: Looks for me like you're spawning threads without properly collecting them. Maybe your thread start and join code and a bit of its surroundings would help?

Comment: Still not enough code for localize the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is still not enough code for localize the problem, but I'm sure that this is because you don't utilize the threads and start too much of them. Did you see canonical example from Queue python documentation http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html (bottom of the page)?

I can reproduce your problem with the following code:

```
import threading
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()

def worker():
    item = q.get(block=True)  # sleeps forever for now
    do_work(item)
    q.task_done()

# create infinite number of workers threads and fails
# after some time with "error: can't start new thread"
while True:
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
q.join() # newer reached this
```

Instead you must create the poll of threads with known number of threads and put your data to queue like:

```
q = Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

UPD: In case you need to stop some thread, you can add a flag to it or send a special mark means "stop" for break `while` loop:

```
class Worker(Thread):
    break_msg = object() # just uniq mark sign

    def __init__(self):
        self.continue = True

    def run():
        while self.continue:  # can stop and destroy thread, (var 1)
            msg = queue.get(block=True)
            if msg == self.break_msg:
                return  # will stop and destroy thread (var 2)
            do_work()
            queue.task_done()

workers = [Worker() for _ in xrange(num_workers)]
for w in workers:
    w.start()
for task in tasks:
    queue.put(task)

for _ in xrange(num_workers):
    queue.put(Worker.break_msg) # stop thread after all tasks done. Need as many messages as many threads you have
OR
queue.join() # wait until all tasks done
for w in workers:
    w.continue = False
    w.put(None)
```

Comment: I am already using 32 threads. I do not think there are too much

Comment: So, i don't know what `SWorker` do and how it cooperate with `Worker` and `WorkerPool`, but if your `while True: t0 = time.time()...` loop do more then one loop - you have a threads leak because you has no "break" in run() method. I will update my response, please wait

Comment: `queue.join() # wait until all tasks done
for w in workers:
    w.continue = False
    w.put(None)`

did the trick.